# how to write a condition for has_many association that joins two tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many, model-associations

I have a user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profile_label_values
  belongs_to :company
end
```

a profile label value model:

```
class profileLabelValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile_label
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and a profile label model:

```
class ProfileLabel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

`ProfileLabel` has two attributes `is_deleted` and `visible`. How can I have my `has_many` association on `ProfileLabelValue` to only return those values whose `ProfileLabels` `is_deleted = false` and `visible = true`?

How can I do a condition in my `has_many :profile_label_values` statement that also checks for these two attributes on `ProfileLabel`?

Comment: As we resolved your question over the chat, for Rails 3.x issue. Please accept the answer when you get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a `M-M relationship` between `User` and `ProfileLabel` model using the join model `ProfileLabelValue`. In order to do that I would suggest you to modify your models as below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ## For Rails 4.x
  ## has_many :profile_label_values, -> { joins(:profile_label).where("profile_labels.is_deleted = ? and profile_labels.visible = ?", false, true ) } 
  ## For Rails 3.x
  has_many :profile_label_values, include: :profile_label, :conditions => "profile_labels.is_deleted = 'f' and profile_labels.visible = 't'"
  has_many :profile_labels, through: :profile_label_values
  belongs_to :company
end

class ProfileLabelValue < ActiveRecord::Base  ## ProfileLabelValue and not profileLabelValue
  belongs_to :profile_label
  belongs_to :user
end

class ProfileLabel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :profile_label_values
  has_many :users, through: :profile_label_values
end
```

Now whenever you invoke `profile_label_values` method on an instance of `User`, you would receive all the `ProfileLabelValue` records whose associated profile_label record has `is_deleted = false` and `visible = true`.

For example:

```
user = User.find(1) ## Get a user record with id 1
user.profile_label_values
```

Comment: thanks but that's not what I need. I need to get profile_label_values that their associating profile_label is not deleted and is visible

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Moved the condition on ` has_many :profile_label_values`. Give it a shot and let me know.

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for expect I can't do this because I'm using rails 3.0. Is there an equivalent for this on rails 3.0 ?

Comment: Let's debug this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror as I don't have Rails 3 but I can guide you